# Different views for different users iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, customization

I am making an app for iPhone which has a Doctors panel, a Nurse panel, a Patient panel and an Admin panel. All the users have different views once they log in. Do I have a way by which I can include all these views in one application and still make it light weight?

I mean to ask, is it possible that once the app gets to know that the user is a Doctor and then it automatically deletes the Admin, Nurse and Patient panel views to reduce the app's space?

Comment: deletes the admin in the sense?

Comment: Well an app can have many views, and you can use conditional logic to decide which view to use, so yes.  However you won't be able to delete anything from the app bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested by @Black Frog you can not modify the package. It is better that you start with rootviewcontroller for the perticular user type.

If you still want to keep the application size minimum, you can load "resource" required for the perticular "type" of user after first login. e.g. Download and save FusionChart's JS and images inside documents directory only if its been used for the perticular user role. similar way for others

-- Vishal

Answer (score 0):

Once the app is compiled, signed and deploy, it cannot modify itself. How big of an app are you talking about?  20 MB? 100 MB? Finish your working prototype first.

Answer (score 0):

You will certainly able to control the flow of the navigation using logic. Have a userType and and load the appropriate view based on that.